# Systemd - how service can determine first run from restart run?

Tags: linux, systemd, embedded

I would like to have a service which behaves differently on first run and on restart of service. Is this possible with systemd? (I use systemd in my embedded os).

I tried with ExecReload and ExecStart, but ExecReload is run only when I use command "systemctl restart". On the other hand ExecStart is run after service Restart ( I have Restart=on-failure and RestartSec=5).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `systemctl set-environment` to push some values into future runs of the service. For example, with a unit:

```
[Unit]
Description=testing
[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/my/command myarg1 ${MYDONE}
ExecStart=/usr/bin/systemctl set-environment MYDONE=1
[Install]
```

On the first `systemctl start <unit>` the last arg passed to `/my/command` will be `''` and `MYDONE` will not be in the environment. On later starts, the last arg will be `1` and `MYDONE=1` will be in the environment.

Comment: This is good. :) By the way I didn't know that i can specify more than one ExecStart in a .service file.

Comment: You are only allowed multiple `ExecStart` if `Type=oneshot`.  But for any type there is also  `ExecStartPre` and  `ExecStartPost`.

Answer (score 1):

You could define the first run in a separate .service file, using

```
[Service]
Type=oneshot
```

Then create another .service file that depends on that one, which will be the one that runs regularly.